# Dynamic columns based on dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table with this data:

```
FirstDiscovered|LastDiscovered|Application|Computer|Organisation
----------------------------------------------------------------
05.03.2017     |05.08.2017    |App A      |Comp 1  |Org 1
----------------------------------------------------------------
04.13.2017     |08.01.2017    |App A      |Comp 2  |Org 1
----------------------------------------------------------------
05.01.2017     |08.01.2017    |App B      |Comp 2  |Org 1
----------------------------------------------------------------
06.13.2017     |08.02.2017    |App A      |Comp 3  |Org 2
----------------------------------------------------------------
07.14.2017     |08.02.2017    |App A      |Comp 4  |Org 2
----------------------------------------------------------------
07.14.2017     |08.02.2017    |App B      |Comp 3  |Org 2
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to extend with a select statement dynamic columns based on  the date attributes "firstDiscovered" and "lastDiscovered".
Let's say there is a row with firstDiscovered = 05.27.17 and lastDiscovered = 06.25.17. Then I expect two new columns May'17 and June'17 filled with "1". All other columns (months) generated by other rows set to '0' or empty, see example:

```
FirstDiscovered|LastDiscovered|Application|Computer|Organisation|Apr 17|May 17|Jun 17|Jul 17|Aug 17
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
05.03.2017     |05.08.2017    |App A      |Comp 1  |Org 1       |0     |1     |0     |0     |0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
04.13.2017     |08.01.2017    |App A      |Comp 2  |Org 1       |1     |1     |1     |1     |1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
05.01.2017     |08.02.2017    |App B      |Comp 2  |Org 1       |0     |1     |1     |1     |1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
06.13.2017     |08.02.2017    |App A      |Comp 3  |Org 2       |0     |0     |1     |1     |1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
07.14.2017     |08.02.2017    |App A      |Comp 4  |Org 2       |0     |0     |0     |1     |1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
07.18.2017     |08.02.2017    |App B      |Comp 3  |Org 2       |0     |0     |0     |1     |1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Would be great if someone will help me.

Comment: What about using CASE based expressions to add the "dynamic" columns?

Comment: My guess you want this dynamic to add all columns between start month and end month and make that dynamic? This is doable but much easier in a cross tab report in SSRS.

Comment: Must be a select statement. Can not use SSRS

Comment: A dynamic PIVOT statement is your solution but really complex.

Comment: Have no idea how to solve this with an dynamic PIVOT statement:-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query as below :

```
select * from #DiscoverData d
cross apply 
( Select top (datediff(mm,d.firstdiscovered, d.lastdiscovered) +1) 
    RowN = Right(Convert(varchar(10), Dateadd(mm, Row_Number() over(order by (Select NULL))-1 , d.FirstDiscovered),6),6)        
    from master..spt_values s1, master..spt_values s2 )  c
pivot (Count(RowN) for RowN in ([Apr 17],[May 17],[Jun 17],[Jul 17], [Aug 17])) p
```

For dynamic list of months you can use query as below:

```
Declare @cols1 varchar(max)
Declare @query nvarchar(max)

Select @cols1 = stuff((
    Select ','+QuoteName(RowN) from ( Select min(firstdiscovered) as firstdiscovered, max(lastdiscovered) as lastdiscovered from #DiscoverData ) d
    cross apply
    ( Select top (datediff(mm,d.firstdiscovered, d.lastdiscovered) +1) 
        RowN = Right(Convert(varchar(10), Dateadd(mm, Row_Number() over(order by (Select NULL))-1 , d.FirstDiscovered),6),6)        
        from master..spt_values s1, master..spt_values s2 )  c
    for xml path('')),1,1,'')

Set @query = ' Select * from #DiscoverData d
    cross apply 
    ( Select top (datediff(mm,d.firstdiscovered, d.lastdiscovered) +1) 
        RowN = Right(Convert(varchar(10), Dateadd(mm, Row_Number() over(order by (Select NULL))-1 , d.FirstDiscovered),6),6)        
        from master..spt_values s1, master..spt_values s2 )  c
    pivot (Count(RowN) for RowN in (' + @cols1 + ')) p '

Exec sp_executesql @query
```

Output as below:

```
+-----------------+----------------+-------------+----------+--------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| FirstDiscovered | lastdiscovered | Application | computer | Organisation | Apr 17 | May 17 | Jun 17 | Jul 17 | Aug 17 |
+-----------------+----------------+-------------+----------+--------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 2017-04-13      | 2017-08-01     | App A       | Comp 2   | Org 1        |      1 |      1 |      1 |      1 |      1 |
| 2017-05-01      | 2017-08-01     | App B       | Comp 2   | Org 1        |      0 |      1 |      1 |      1 |      1 |
| 2017-05-03      | 2017-05-08     | App A       | Comp 1   | Org 1        |      0 |      1 |      0 |      0 |      0 |
| 2017-06-13      | 2017-08-02     | App A       | Comp 3   | Org 2        |      0 |      0 |      1 |      1 |      1 |
| 2017-07-14      | 2017-08-02     | App A       | Comp 4   | Org 2        |      0 |      0 |      0 |      1 |      1 |
| 2017-07-14      | 2017-08-02     | App B       | Comp 3   | Org 2        |      0 |      0 |      0 |      1 |      1 |
+-----------------+----------------+-------------+----------+--------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: The dynamic month query is running in general.
But I get the message "TOP clause contains an invalid value."
The result doesn't show all data

Comment: Which means you are have some negative data in the difference between firstdiscovered and last discovered. What we need to do during that scenario?